# what is the difference between object and loader heap in .net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

basically i like to know how static classes are handled by clr?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

heap memory is divided into to parts,object heap and loader heap(also known as high frequency heap).All non static reference type are stored on object heap and all static object(either reference type or value type) are stored in loader heap.
Gc never work on loader heap thats why they initilized only once and remain in memory throught the application.